# react constants import using props drill vs context vs imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, import

I have inherited some code that uses props drilling to pass down a large list of constants (translations) to various sub components. These translations map a symbol to a local language text and there is also a function to do the mapping called translate. ie {translate(SYM_NO)} would return "NON" if the local language was French.

I thought Props drilling was a bit messy and decided to use the new Context in React 16.3.1. This worked OK for JSX, but was a bit tricky when I needed to get translate into JS eg a MS Fabric UI DetailsList callback so that the callback could translate various column data (returned by an API call). Below is a technique for adding a parameter (from Context) to the callback which can then be used in the callback implementation:

```
onRenderItemColumn={(item, index, column) => this._renderItemColumn(item, index, column, translate)}
```

After getting this to work, I discovered that it was actually unececessary, as I could just import translation in any (most) of my components and easily use translate anywhere in my JSX or JS :-

```
import translate from "../../../config/translate";
```

So I am now wondering about the performance/memory implications of importing translate in nearly all of my components. Is there a penalty for every import or is it just the first import that counts and the rest have no impact?

Should I continue with many imports or revert to (trickier) Context or perhaps some other method. (Props drilling is not an option I think)

Peter (React newb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your using a standard Webpack based React stack the overhead with regards to performance should be minimal since they all are references the same module which is only evaluated once. Maintenance wise, in my experience, it will soon become a burden. Especially when you take into account that imports are relative to the file you import in. "is this file four levels deep or six". Making moving files a pain. And adding aliases for some modules so you can import them with an absolute path increases the complexity for new developers.

Context would not be the best approach I think since you need to add consumers to all parts that need translations.

What I would advise you to look into is if higher order components click for you. That has the benefits of not cluttering your components render logic with consumers and can be added as extra functionality to all components who need translations in a pretty transparent way. In pseudo code: `export default withTranslations(Component);`
You would still need to import the withTranslation where you would import your config/translations module but implementation wise it would make more sense to me.

Also there are some NPM modules for i18n in React and all the ones I've used also use the higher order component approach, which makes me believe that it can also work for you.

Comment: Regarding import-problem of path being relative to the file: This can be solved by creating a jsconfig.json with ```{"compilerOptions": {"baseUrl": "src"}}```  and reg. problem of adding many Context  consumers: one can use a HOC for this.